# Error while creating volume in openstack

Tags: openstack

I installed devstack of openstack.

When I login using admin user and create a volume. It shows error as a status.

I got following in error log (syslog file). But couldn't find any resolution by google. What's wrong happening with this.

```
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00mConnectionFailedError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.43.88', port=2379): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3alpha/lease/grant (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4b75d3c110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] ENETUNREACH',))
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: #033[00;32mDEBUG oslo_concurrency.lockutils [#033[01;36mNone req-a2a87ca1-802a-4e3d-abe9-e28601906c44 #033[00;36mNone None#033[00;32m] #033[01;35m#033[00;32mAcquired semaphore "singleton_lock"#033[00m #033[00;33m{{(pid=3263) lock /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_concurrency/lockutils.py:212}}#033[00m
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: #033[00;32mDEBUG oslo_concurrency.lockutils [#033[01;36mNone req-a2a87ca1-802a-4e3d-abe9-e28601906c44 #033[00;36mNone None#033[00;32m] #033[01;35m#033[00;32mReleasing semaphore "singleton_lock"#033[00m #033[00;33m{{(pid=3263) lock /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_concurrency/lockutils.py:228}}#033[00m
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: #033[00;36mINFO oslo_service.service [#033[01;36mNone req-a2a87ca1-802a-4e3d-abe9-e28601906c44 #033[00;36mNone None#033[00;36m] #033[01;35m#033[00;36mChild 3263 exited with status 1#033[00m
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: #033[00;32mDEBUG oslo_service.service [#033[01;36mNone req-a2a87ca1-802a-4e3d-abe9-e28601906c44 #033[00;36mNone None#033[00;32m] #033[01;35m#033[00;32mStarted child 3264#033[00m #033[00;33m{{(pid=707) _start_child /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_service/service.py:577}}#033[00m
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: #033[00;36mINFO cinder.service [#033[00;36m-#033[00;36m] #033[01;35m#033[00;36mStarting cinder-volume node (version 13.0.0)#033[00m
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: #033[01;31mERROR oslo_service.service [#033[00;36m-#033[01;31m] #033[01;35m#033[01;31mError starting thread.#033[00m: ConnectionFailedError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.43.88', port=2379): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3alpha/lease/grant (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4b75d3c110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] ENETUNREACH',))
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00mTraceback (most recent call last):
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_service/service.py", line 792, in run_service
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m    service.start()
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m  File "/opt/stack/cinder/cinder/service.py", line 219, in start
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m    coordination.COORDINATOR.start()
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m  File "/opt/stack/cinder/cinder/coordination.py", line 67, in start
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m    self.coordinator.start(start_heart=True)
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tooz/coordination.py", line 687, in start
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m    super(CoordinationDriverWithExecutor, self).start(start_heart)
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tooz/coordination.py", line 423, in start
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m    self._start()
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tooz/drivers/etcd3gw.py", line 196, in _start
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m    self._membership_lease = self.client.lease(self.membership_timeout)
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/etcd3gw/client.py", line 115, in lease
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m    json={"TTL": ttl, "ID": 0})
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/etcd3gw/client.py", line 88, in post
Jun 21 13:29:08 krishna-Lenovo-G550 cinder-volume[707]: ERROR oslo_service.service #033[01;35m#033[00m    raise exceptions.ConnectionFailedError(six.text_type(ex))
```

I have ubuntu 18.04 LTS boot from 64 gb USB.

Volume size is -> 1 GB.

Volume type is -> lvmdriver-1.

Volume source is -> No source, empty volume

As per following reference.

https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/51180/error-connectionerror-httpconnectionpoolhostopenstack-port8774-max-retries-exceeded-with-url-v24ca42a660b0c4ff48db51d3187215dd4imagesdetail-caused-by/

following command.

```
sudo nova-manage service list
```

gives following.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
usage: nova-manage [-h] [--remote_debug-host REMOTE_DEBUG_HOST]
                   [--remote_debug-port REMOTE_DEBUG_PORT] [--config-dir DIR]
                   [--config-file PATH] [--debug] [--log-config-append PATH]
                   [--log-date-format DATE_FORMAT] [--log-dir LOG_DIR]
                   [--log-file PATH] [--nodebug] [--nopost-mortem]
                   [--nouse-journal] [--nouse-json] [--nouse-syslog]
                   [--nowatch-log-file] [--post-mortem]
                   [--syslog-log-facility SYSLOG_LOG_FACILITY] [--use-journal]
                   [--use-json] [--use-syslog] [--version] [--watch-log-file]
                   {version,bash-completion,placement,network,cell_v2,db,cell,floating,api_db}
                   ...
nova-manage: error: argument category: invalid choice: 'service' (choose from 'version', 'bash-completion', 'placement', 'network', 'cell_v2', 'db', 'cell', 'floating', 'api_db')
```

Following command:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl status
```

gives following:

```
Status of node 'rabbit@krishna-Lenovo-G550'
[{pid,1851},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.10"},
      {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.","1.3.0"},
      {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","8.2.3"},
      {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","1.5.2"},
      {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 5.0.4","5.0.4"},
      {crypto,"CRYPTO","4.2"},
      {rabbit_common,
          "Modules shared by rabbitmq-server and rabbitmq-erlang-client",
          "3.6.10"},
      {compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","7.1.4"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.16"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.4.4"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.15.3"},
      {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","2.1.4"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","3.1.1"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.4.3"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","5.4.1"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
     [{total,127617792},
      {connection_readers,813376},
      {connection_writers,57704},
      {connection_channels,182760},
      {connection_other,1578088},
      {queue_procs,747128},
      {queue_slave_procs,0},
      {plugins,0},
      {other_proc,17494600},
      {mnesia,173768},
      {metrics,271752},
      {mgmt_db,0},
      {msg_index,58592},
      {other_ets,1914184},
      {binary,73692752},
      {code,21401226},
      {atom,900041},
      {other_system,8600765}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,3317874688},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,44431437824},
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,65436},
      {total_used,30},
      {sockets_limit,58890},
      {sockets_used,28}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,549}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,5312},
 {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the nova services status the command is:

**Using openstack CLI**:

```
 openstack compute service list
```

**Using nova CLI**:

```
 nova service-list
```